# Unity: Access classes in Assembly-CSharp from playmode tests

Tags: unity-game-engine

is it possible to reference Assembly-CSharp in play mode tests? I would like to test/use scripts in my tests but don't know how to reference Assembly-CSharp.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was answered in the Unity forum by the User 'MafiaMoe':

> The 'solution' is to right-click on the Test Runner tab and click
> 'Enable playmode tests for all assemblies'. Then (after a restart of
> Unity) playmode tests can be written directly in the game scripts. I
> think this video has a good example: [youtube](https://youtu.be/MWS4aSO7HAo?t=9m50s)
>
> However, after working play mode tests into our game development
> routine, I think I have a better idea how this is all supposed to work. > What we have been doing is keeping the 'Enable playmode tests for all
> assemblies' OFF and setting up test scenes that are already pre-
> configured to 'run-on-load'. With that, all the playmode test scripts
> need to do is load the scene and assert that certain log messages show
> up.
>
> This seems to keep the process of creating and maintaining tests less
> convoluted, as almost all of the configuration happens within the
> editor. This also means no playmode tests are awkwardly included in the > game scripts, when this type of test seems best suited to validate
> interactions between multiple scripts within a game scene.

Comment: Note that as of 2021 the feature seems disabled, and creating custom assemblies for your game scripts seems to be the (only) right way. See https://forum.unity.com/threads/enable-playmode-tests-for-all-assemblies-option-missing.1078463/